# Spring Boot + Lettuce + Redis-Sentinel without own beans?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, lettuce, redis-sentinel

In our Spring Boot-App, we are using `Spring Data` and `Spring Cache` together with `Lettuce` to connect to a `REDIS`-Cluster.
We are currently switching to a Sentinel-Connection-setup.

**We are asking ourselves if there is another way to setup Lettuce/Redis-Sentinel than what we have come up with.**

**This works:**
Excerpt from `application.yml`:

```
redis:
  sentinel:
    master: # master name does not matter
  port: # port still does not matter
  host: # hostname does not matter
  password: # password does not matter
```

Setting `connect-timeout` and `timeout` in `application.yml` does not suffice anymore. Because we define our own `LettuceConnectionFactory`-Bean. To be able to setup a `RedisSentinelConfiguration`.

Excerpt from `CacheConfig.java`:

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration()
        .master(sentinelMaster)
        .sentinel(sentinelHost, Integer.valueOf(sentinelPort));
sentinelConfig.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisPassword));

SocketOptions socketOptions = SocketOptions.builder()
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1L))
        .build();

ClientOptions clientOptions = ClientOptions.builder()
        .socketOptions(socketOptions)
        .timeoutOptions(TimeoutOptions.enabled())
        .build();

LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
        .commandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1L))
        .clientOptions(clientOptions)
        .build();


return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig, lettuceClientConfiguration);
}
```

We use this `LettuceConnectionFactory` in our `RedisCacheManager`:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
return RedisCacheManager
        .RedisCacheManagerBuilder
        .fromConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory)
        .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(Duration.parse(defaultCacheTtl)))
        .build();
}
```

**If it works, why bother?**

What we liked before, was the option to set `connect-timeout` and `timeout` in our `application.yml` and have Spring Boot/Lettuce do the trick (setup `LettuceConnectionFactory` etc.) for us. We did not have to bother about other defaults and settings within this Connection.

**So the question remains:** Is there another way than providing a custom `LettuceConnectionFactory`-Bean to:

- setup `Lettuce` using a `RedisSentinelConfiguration`
- set both `connect-timeout` and `timeout` without all the `builder()` functions

**For Example:** Is it possible to setup another Bean (possibly a `RedisSentinelConfiguration`-Bean) which is then autowired during Autoconfiguration? Or is there a "config-only" approach (simply setting properties in `application.yml`)?